# c++ STL using vector<SafeList> resize failed

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I defined a ThreadSafe List and I want to declear a vector to save some ThreadSafe list, but when I initialized the vector using resize, I got some error.

The SafeList I defined:

```
template<class T>
class SafeQueue{
public:
    SafeQueue() {}
    SafeQueue(const SafeQueue & sq) = delete;
    SafeQueue & operator = (const SafeQueue & sq) = delete;

private:
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
```

And the Initialization code is:

```cpp
for (auto & p : timer_) {
    // p type: std::vector<SafeContainer::SafeList<TimerNodePtr> >
    p.resize(SHIFT);
}
```

And the error information followed:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*>; _ForwardIterator = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:307:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*>; _ForwardIterator = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*; _Tp = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:329:2:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*; _ForwardIterator = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >*; _Allocator = std::allocator<SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> > >]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/vector.tcc:659:48:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:937:4:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<SafeContainer::SafeList<std::shared_ptr<Timer::TimerNode> > >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/home/ctrlz/workSpace/MyServer/src/Timer.cpp:8:23:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:127:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
  127 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

---

minimal reproducible example as followed:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
template<class T>
class SafeQueue{
public:
    SafeQueue() {}
    SafeQueue(const SafeQueue & sq) = delete;
    SafeQueue & operator = (const SafeQueue & sq) = delete;


private:
    std::queue<T> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<SafeQueue<int> > list;
    list.resize(5);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Also, search for the error message online and read the surrounding code.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example  has been given to title.

Comment: Almost, the template part and the mutex can probably be removed as well. Anyhow, have you also done the research on the error message? It's not new and there are several similar questions already!

Answer (score 0):

The overload of [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) you are calling requires the elements to be [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable) and [DefaultInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable). With the default allocator MoveInsertable effectively requires the elements to be move constructible, but your `SafeQueue` isn't. This assert fails:

```
static_assert( std::is_move_constructible_v<SafeQueue<int>> );
```

See here: https://godbolt.org/z/1c16zbzv8

In fact, there is not much you can do with a vector of non-copyable, non-assignable and non-moveable elements. Assume you could resize, but then you would not be able to assign to the elements. Reallocations also require to move elements.